# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS Man Pages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My group and I are currently working on creating man pages for various ROS commands. We are just unsure about how we are to submit them to the github repository. Since this is creating new files we are unsure about what kind of file structure you are looking for.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248579/ros-man-pages/) by [JWMH](https://answers.ros.org/users/27964/jwmh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63573/how-is-the-path-to-search-for-man-pages-set ; the default configuration of `man` on Ubuntu will look for man pages in share/man next to any bin directory in the `PATH` environment variable.

Probably the best way to integrate this into ROS is to include the man pages within the source code that they document, and then set up install rules to install them into share/man ( `${CATKIN_GLOBAL_SHARE_DESTINATION}/man` in the catkin install rules )

This also makes it easy to have different man pages for each version of ROS, if multiple versions of ROS are installed side-by-side.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1